# How do I increase the size of a TextView when the user clicks a button?

Tags: android

How do I increase the size of a TextView when the user clicks a button?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following piece of code inside the on click method

> yourtextview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,14);

give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: This is how i would do it as well ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go about doing this by using the TextView size property.

In the onClick of the button, you could call the setTextSize(int,float) property to increase or decrease the size.

You would probably need a variable as well to increment the size based on the value & then after the variable becomes 5 you could reduce the size back to the original size

Hope this helps.

Comment: public void varySize(){        textview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,18); x++ ; }

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Zoom extends Activity
{
private String productName;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.zoom);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        productName = intent.getStringExtra("ChoosenMed");

        TextView productNameTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.prodcutNameZoomTextView);
  productNameTextView.setText(productName);

 }
}
```